# How to write Map/Reduce tasks in Golang?

Tags: hadoop, go

I would like to write Hadoop Map/Reduce jobs in Go (and not the Streaming API!) .

I tried to get a grasp of [hortonworks/gohadoop](https://github.com/hortonworks/gohadoop) and [colinmarc/hdfs](https://github.com/colinmarc/hdfs) but I still don't see how to write jobs for real. I have searched on github codes importing these modules but there is nothing relevant apparently.

Is there any `WordCount.go` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This github: https://github.com/vistarmedia/gossamr is a good example for starting to use a golang job on Hadoop:

Jist:

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "strings"

  "github.com/vistarmedia/gossamr"
)

type WordCount struct{}

func (wc *WordCount) Map(p int64, line string, c gossamr.Collector) error {
  for _, word := range strings.Fields(line) {
    c.Collect(strings.ToLower(word), int64(1))
  }
  return nil
}

func (wc *WordCount) Reduce(word string, counts chan int64, c gossamr.Collector) error {
  var sum int64
  for v := range counts {
    sum += v
  }
  c.Collect(sum, word)
  return nil
}

func main() {
  wordcount := gossamr.NewTask(&WordCount{})

  err := gossamr.Run(wordcount)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Kicking off the script:

```
./bin/hadoop jar ./contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar \
  -input /mytext.txt \
  -output /output.15 \
  -mapper "gossamr -task 0 -phase map" \
  -reducer "gossamr -task 0 -phase reduce" \
  -io typedbytes \
  -file ./wordcount
  -numReduceTasks 6
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for your contribution! But your code is using the Hadoop Streaming API and I stated that i was not interested with it.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple implementation of Map/Reduce written in Golang (available at github):

https://github.com/dbravender/go_mapreduce

Comment: Where is the link with Hadoop?